# Is it possible to prevent gimbal lock on a 2 axis gimble by adding a 3rd axis treating it as an "2d" quaternion?

Tags: quaternions

If I have a 2 axis gimbal, that functions similar to a [theodolite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodolite), that rotates the pitch and yaw axis. If I were to add an axis to make it a traditional [gimbal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal), would I be able to prevent the [gimbal-lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock) that occurs at zenith and nadir by treating the system as a quaternion with 3 variables instead of 4?

Where:

- Pitch = Pitch Axis * sin(Angle / 2)
- Yaw = Yaw Axis * sin(Angle / 2)
- Roll = cos(Angle / 2)

The value of roll is not important, but would keeping it like this prevent the Pitch and Yaw axis's alignment?

Comment: Have you checked https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation ?

Comment: Sorry I should clarify that in this particular situation using a normal quaternion or transformation matrix is not an option and that all end rotations must be Eucler.